# T-SQL Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures, type-conversion

I am using the following stored procedure which takes a datetime variable as input

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.report @createfrom as datetime=null,@createto as datetime=null
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql varchar(1000)
    declare @s datetime;
    declare @s1 datetime;

    --set @createfrom='7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM'(my input is like in this format)
    set @sql = N'select * from table1 where createdon >=''' + cast(@createfrom as datetime) + '''and createdon <=''' + cast(@createto as datetime) + ''' AND createdon is not null'

    exec(@sql) 
END
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. `createdon` is a `datetime` variable in the table1. I have given the input parameter format within the code itself. I want to stick to `cast` instead of `convert`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you wanted to stick to cast over convert, but it might be best to format the date as yyyymmdd in your string

e.g.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.report @createfrom as datetime=null,@createto as datetime=null
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql varchar(1000)
    declare @s datetime;
    declare @s1 datetime;

    --set @createfrom='7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM'(my input is like in this format)
    set @sql = N'select * from table1 where createdon >=''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @createfrom, 112) + '''and createdon <=''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @createto, 112) + ''' AND createdon is not null'

    exec(@sql) 
END
```

Comment: Well ,may be i will conveniently ignore 'cast',yes this did the work